# Bluetooth not working as expected on Lumia 610

Tags: lumia, 7.5, bluetooth

I tried to bluetooth some photos to a Nokia Lumia 610 from my Nokia N8, and each time my N8 said "failed to connect". I then tried pairing the 610 with the N8, and while it said "Pairing Successful" on both phones, the Lumia immediately popped up a message next to the N8's label which said "Not supported". Numerous attempts failed, despite trying to bluetooth between two N8's and two Lumia 610's (swapping each phone around to see which combination would work).

Bluetooth between the two 610's works fine; between the two N8's is fine. What could be the problem, seeing as the pairing operation between the two phones was successful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe this is currently supported by the Lumia phones, however it's been announced as coming with their [7.8 update](http://conversations.nokia.com/2012/09/11/great-times-ahead-for-all-nokia-lumia-smartphones/):

> Bluetooth file transfer to send media files via Bluetooth from your Lumia device to any other phone

Comment: Really? Was I wrong to assume such a basic function should exist in the Lumia? Eish. Anyway, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2):

Bluetooth is not working in WP 7.5 Mango, It is working in WP 7.8.
You can update the OS in nearest Nokia care.
If you want to update through Internet means, Not possible now. It may be first quarter of this year.

Comment: Yes, that is correct that in 7.8 it allows for "normal" Bluetooth functionality.